# Odoo JavaScript Renderer Issue

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo

I have a problem with JavaScript in Odoo, I've created a tree view which open inside a wizard!
the button appears on bottom at first time opening the wizard AND I CANNOT CLICK IT, but if I apply a filter or a group by AND THEN REMOVE IT, the button become at the top (header) and becomes clickable and works fine.
( Please see the screenshots so you can understand more what I am talking about)

[image: The Button that opens the wizard]

[image: The first time the wizard opens - button not clickable]

[image: I apply a filter]

[image: I remove the filter]

[image: Now the button is working fine]

Wizaard Tree view :

```
<record id="compatible_products_wizard_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">compatible.products.wizard.tree</field>
        <field name="model">compatible.products.wizard</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Selected Products" create="0" edit="0" export_xlsx="false" js_class="buttton_in_tree">
                <field name="mrp_id"/>
                <field name="product_id"/>
                <field name="lst_price"/>
                <field name="standard_price"/>
                <field name="qty_available"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
</record>
```

Button Template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<templates>
    <t t-extend="ListView.buttons" t-name="de_alfa_web_connector.buttons">
        <t t-jquery=".o_list_buttons" t-operation="replace">
            <div class="o_list_buttons" role="toolbar" aria-label="Main actions">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info open_wizard_action" style="display:none;">
                    Create Moves
                </button>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
    <t t-extend="ListView.selection">
        <t t-jquery=".o_list_select_domain" t-operation="after">
            <button t-if="nbSelected > 0" type="button" class="btn btn-info open_wizard_action">
                Create Moves
            </button>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

JS Code :

```
odoo.define('de_alfa_web_connector.tree_button', function (require) {
    "use strict";
    var core = require('web.core');
    var ListController = require('web.ListController');
    var ListRenderer = require('web.ListRenderer');
    var ListView = require('web.ListView');
    var viewRegistry = require('web.view_registry');
    var TreeButton = ListController.extend({
        buttons_template: 'de_alfa_web_connector.buttons',
        events: _.extend({}, ListController.prototype.events, {
            'click .open_wizard_action': '_OpenWizard',
        }),

        _OpenWizard: function (ev) {
            var treeView = this.renderer;
            var checkedRows = treeView.$("tbody input[type='checkbox']:checked").closest('tr');
            var extractedData = [];
            checkedRows.each(function () {
                var rowData = {};
                $(this).find('td').each(function (columnIndex) {
                    var inputElement = $(this).find('input, select');
                    if (inputElement.length > 0) {
                        rowData[columnIndex] = inputElement.val().trim();
                    } else {
                        rowData[columnIndex] = $(this).text().trim();
                    }
                });
                extractedData.push(rowData);
            });

            var self = this;
            var lineVals = [];
            var promises = [];
            var Active_id;
            console.log('Extracted', extractedData);
            extractedData.forEach(function (data) {
                Active_id = data[1];
                Active_id = Active_id.replace(/,/g, '');
                Active_id = parseInt(Active_id);
                var firstSplit = data[2].split('[');
                var lastSplit = firstSplit[1].split(']');
                var OldId = lastSplit[0];
                var p_name = data[2];

                var productPromise = self._rpc({
                    model: 'product.product',
                    method: 'search_read',
                    args: [[['old_id', '=', OldId]], ['id', 'name', 'uom_id', 'product_tmpl_id']],
                }).then(function (result) {
                    return result[0] || false;
                });
                promises.push(productPromise);

                var linePromise = Promise.all([productPromise]).then(function (results) {
                    var product = results[0];
                    if (product) {
                        var line = [0, 0, {
                            'product_id': product.id,
                            'name': p_name,
                            'product_uom_qty': 1,
                            'product_uom': product.uom_id[0],
                            'raw_material_production_id': Active_id,
                            'location_id': 15,
                            'location_dest_id': 8,
                            'picking_type_id': 41,
                        }];
                        lineVals.push(line);
                    }
                });
                promises.push(linePromise);
            });

            Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
                if (lineVals.length > 0) {
                    var moveLineVals = lineVals.map(function (lineVal) {
                        return lineVal[2];
                    });

                    var movePromise = self._rpc({
                        model: 'stock.move',
                        method: 'create',
                        args: [moveLineVals],
                    });

                    movePromise.then(function (result) {
                        console.log('Lines created successfully:', result);
                        // Update move_raw_ids field of mrp.production with the created stock.move IDs
                        var productionID = Active_id;
//                        var productionPromise = self._rpc({
//                            model: 'mrp.production',
//                            method: 'write',
//                            args: [[productionID], { move_raw_ids: result }],
//                        });
                        var productionPromise = self._rpc({
                                model: 'mrp.production',
                                method: 'read',
                                args: [[productionID], ['move_raw_ids']],
                            }).then(function (production) {
                                    var existingMoveRawIds = production[0].move_raw_ids || [];
                                    var updatedMoveRawIds = existingMoveRawIds.concat(result);
                                    return self._rpc({
                                            model: 'mrp.production',
                                            method: 'write',
                                                args: [[productionID], { move_raw_ids: updatedMoveRawIds }],
                                                });
                                });

                        productionPromise.then(function () {
                            console.log('move_raw_ids field updated successfully');
                            self.trigger_up('history_back');
                        }).guardedCatch(function (error) {
                            console.error('Failed to update move_raw_ids field:', error);
                        });
                    }).guardedCatch(function (error) {
                        console.error('Failed to create lines:', error);
                    });
                }
            });
        },
    });

    var CompatibleProductsListView = ListView.extend({
        config: _.extend({}, ListView.prototype.config, {
            Controller: TreeButton,
        }),
    });

    viewRegistry.add('buttton_in_tree', CompatibleProductsListView);
});
```

Python code :

```
    def open_compatible_products_wizard(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        compatible_products = self.move_raw_ids_compatible_products
        sql = "delete from compatible_products_wizard"
        self.env.cr.execute(sql)
        m_id = self.id
        for item in compatible_products:
            wizard = self.env['compatible.products.wizard'].create({
                'mrp_id': m_id,
                'product_id': item.id,
            })

        return {
            'name': 'Compatible Products',
            'view_mode': 'tree',
            'view_id': self.env.ref('de_alfa_web_connector.compatible_products_wizard_tree_view').id,
            'res_model': 'compatible.products.wizard',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'target': 'new',


        }
```

Comment: Could you provide the python code generating your wizard too please ?

Comment: You want to generate multiple wizards?

Comment: in mrp.production module, the user choose product_id which is a printer, when clicking the the button Add Multiple Products, it open the product which are compatible with the printer in a list view, when checking & validating by Create Moves, the records are created in move_raw_ids One2many (stock.move) field in mrp.production.

Comment: Open the browser's developer console (usually by pressing F12) and look for any JavaScript errors that happen when opening your wizard  and report them here

Comment: ...add debbuger in your js-code: _OpenWizard: function (ev) { debugger .... and follow step by step the live execution of your script

Comment: Thank you for you time and response
the _OpenWizard is working perfectly, I think there is a problem with the renderer not in the function because the errors appears right after opening the wizards, then it dispappears, it has no relation with the code inside the function _OpenWizard
++ in the console I have no errors.